# error in add_p()' for variable X and test 'fisher.test', p-value omitted

Tags: r, gtsummary

I get the error below when I try to use the add_p() function to get a p-value for differences between my by variable (with 10 levels) and a categorical variable with two levels (yes/no). I am not sure how to provide a reproducible example. From the trials data, I imagine my **by** variable would be the "T Stage" variable with 10 levels, and the categorical variables would be: (1) "Chemotherapy Treatment" with 2 levels, and (2) "Chemotherapy Treatment2" with 4 levels. But here is the code I ran.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
miro_def %>% 
  select(mheim, age_dx, time_t1d_yrs, gender, collard, fhist_pandz) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = mheim, missing = "no",
              type = list(c(gender, collard, fhist_pandz, mheim) ~ "categorical"),
              label = list(gender ~ "Gender", 
                           fhist_pandz ~ "Family history of PD", 
                           age_dx ~ "Age at diagnosis", 
                           time_t1d_yrs ~ "Follow-up(years)")) %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  # style the output with custom header 
  #modify_header(stat_by = "{level}") %>% 
  # convert to kableExtra as_kable_extra(booktabs = TRUE) %>% 
  # reduce font size to make table fit. # you may also use the `latex_options = "scale_down"` argument here. 
  kable_styling(font_size = 7, latex_options = "scale_down")
```

However, I do get a p-value for this by variable (10 levels) with other variables (which are continous/numeric)

1. How can I fix this error?
2. In the case where I have the mentioned multilevel by variable and a multilevel (>2 levels) categorical variable, is there something special I should do to get a p-value?

   There was an error in 'add_p()' for variable 'gender' and test 'fisher.test', p-value omitted:
   Error in stats::fisher.test(data[[variable]], as.factor(data[[by]])): FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18540 is too small for this problem,
   (pastp=51.2364, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=150]=215, stp[ipn_0]=40.6787).
   Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'
   There was an error in 'add_p()' for variable 'collard' and test 'fisher.test', p-value omitted:
   Error in stats::fisher.test(data[[variable]], as.factor(data[[by]])): FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18570 is too small for this problem,
   (pastp=37.0199, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=211]=823, stp[ipn_0]=23.0304).
   Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'
   There was an error in 'add_p()' for variable 'fhist_pandz' and test 'fisher.test', p-value omitted:
   Error in stats::fisher.test(data[[variable]], as.factor(data[[by]])): FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18570 is too small for this problem,
   (pastp=36.4614, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=58]=1, stp[ipn_0]=31.8106).
   Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'

Comment: Hi Nelly, what do you get when you do `fisher.test(as.factor(miro_def$gender), as.factor(miro_def$mheim))`? Also, can you show us what `table(as.factor(miro_def$gender), as.factor(miro_def$mheim))` looks like? I suspect that fisher.test just may not be able to run, it may not be a gtsummary issue!

Comment: `> fisher.test(miro_def$gender, miro_def$mheim)
Error in fisher.test(miro_def$gender, miro_def$mheim) : 
  FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18540 is too small for this problem,
  (pastp=51.2364, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=150]=215, stp[ipn_0]=40.6787).
Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'`

Comment: `> table(as.factor(miro_def$gender), as.factor(miro_def$mheim))
        
         Alc AlcNic Eff Her HerEff ImmNicAlc Msc Nic Nut Une
  female   9     72  37  23      2        25  17  51   0  24
  male    49    193  39  24      3        43  10  52   6  32`

Comment: Hi Margaret, In case this cannot be resolved by your team: (1) Where or which forum and what tags - if this forum -  would you recommend I use to increase the chance of a response? (2) Say I get a solution, how do I then port it to gtsummary so that I still get the nice tables? Thanks

Comment: HI @Nelly! It looks like @Margaret diagnosed the problem.  Your data is erring with the `fisher.test()`, which is why you're not getting the output in `add_p()`. First, look for a test that is appropriate for your data, then try that test in `add_p()`. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since nobody posted an answer, here's what I used when coming across this. Following the Examples given in the help file `?gtsummary::add_p.tbl_summary`, I composed a custom function that runs `fisher.test` with the `simulate.p.values = TRUE` option:

```
## define custom test
fisher.test.simulate.p.values <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  result <- list()
  test_results <- stats::fisher.test(data[[variable]], data[[by]], simulate.p.value = TRUE)
  result$p <- test_results$p.value
  result$test <- test_results$method
  result
}

## add p-values to your gtsummary table, using custom test defined above
summary_table %>%
add_p(
  test = list(all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test.simulate.p.values")  # this applies the custom test to all categorical variables
)
```

You can also amend the number of iterations for computing the simulated p-values by changing the default `B = 2000` parameter to `fisher.test()` above.

All this assumes, of course, that it's appropriate to use Fisher's test in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Since it fixed the issue for me, I would like to indicate that since version `1.3.6` of `gtsummary` there is an option in `add_p()` with which you can specify arguments to the test functions (i.e. `test.args`). Thank you to the developers for this!

From the [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtsummary/news/news.html):
Each `add_p()` method now has the `test.args = argument`. Use this argument to pass
additional arguments to the statistical method, e.g.

```
add_p(test = c(age, marker) ~ "t.test",
      test.args = c(age, marker) ~ list(var.equal = TRUE))
```

It is also explained in the `add_p()` help (i.e. `?add_p`).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. You have to increase your workspace with `test.args` within `add_p()`.

```
miro_def %>% 
  select(mheim, age_dx, time_t1d_yrs, gender, collard, fhist_pandz) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = mheim, missing = "no",
              type = list(c(gender, collard, fhist_pandz, mheim) ~ "categorical"),
              label = list(gender ~ "Gender", 
                           fhist_pandz ~ "Family history of PD", 
                           age_dx ~ "Age at diagnosis", 
                           time_t1d_yrs ~ "Follow-up(years)")) %>% 
  add_p(test.args = variable_with_no_pval ~ list(workspace=2e9))
```

or

```
add_p(test.args = all_test("fisher.test") ~ list(workspace=2e9))
```

Comment: The latest line should I think be updated as *add_p(test.args = all_tests("fisher.test") ~ list(workspace=2e9))* -- i.e. all_test in plural

Comment: Yes, as @ChristHope says, last line should use all_tests() not all_test()